# Good reference for Object Oriented Design

Tags: oop, object

I find myself rarely using object oriented principles when I design applications. I am looking for a good reference for Object Oriented design. I'm using C# as my programming language and would like to have a reference which helps to make use of the OO contructs provided by C#. But basically I need a good book to derive some inspiration.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574001/what-books-do-you-suggest-for-understanding-object-oriented-programming-design-de among many, many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes: two milestones

1. [Design Patterns: Elements of
   Reusable Object-Oriented
   Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)
2. [Head First Design
   Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/)

Comment: I would add "head first object oriented analysis and design" to that list as well

Comment: Which one do you recommend to read first?

Comment: Head first is more "readable" than GoF

Answer (score 1):

I think a book on Design Patterns may be what you want. The classic one would be Deisgn Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object Orientated Software.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Evan's DDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)