# Creating my own python module - questions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating my own python module that has some functions I want to use. I wanna know how to do these things:

- How do I proceed with my python module called module.py, so I import only the functions I want, when calling 'import module.function'? (so I don't have to import the entire module)
- Does I always have to create a class for my functions, even if I would never use more than ONE object of that class? (if not, how to create a function that has all the self variables inside, so them don't mess up with global variables from the entire code?) (but without use def fun(self, var1, var2...) because I don't want to call fun("", var1, var2...)
- Is it better to 'install' my module or use it like a external file?

Comment: Please clarify your second point.  What do you mean by "a function that has all the self variables inside", etc.?

Comment: self.var1, self.var2, so I can use any variable in my code and it will not mess up with the variables inside the function

Answer (score 2):

1. How do I proceed with my python module called module.py, so I import only the functions I want, when calling 'import module.function'? (so I don't have to import the entire module)

Using the syntax

```
from mymodule import myobject
```

you can import any object declared at the top level of your module file (you can also override this to hide some objects, by declaring all your "public" objects in the `__all__` object). But as @BrenBam said, whether you do `from mymodule ...` or `import module`, the interpreter will still load all top level objects from that module, but only exposing the ones you're selecting.

2. Does I always have to create a class for my functions, even if I would never use more than ONE object of that class? (if not, how to create a function that has all the self variables inside, so them don't mess up with global variables from the entire code?) (but without use def fun(self, var1, var2...) because I don't want to call fun("", var1, var2...)

It's a OOP software design question you're asking. Per definition a function has arguments and one output and that's about all, e.g.:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1+arg2
```

and its usage can't be more simple:

```
>>> print foo(1,2)
3
```

A method is a function bound to a class, that (in python) has a reference for the current object (or class):

```
class Foo():
    def set_arg1(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1
    def set_arg2(self, arg2):
        self.arg2 = arg2
    def foo(self):
        return self.arg1+self.arg2
```

then you instanciate the `Foo` class into an object, and make it work on data:

```
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar.set_arg1(1)
>>> bar.set_arg2(2)
>>> print bar.foo()
3
```

then when you're making a module, you declare functions and objects depending on what you need them to do. If you have a set of functions that work on the same set of variables, you will want to encapsulate them as "members" in a class, make the functions into methods that will act on those members, creating a behavior for the class and expose the class to the users of your module. They will then instanciate your class into objects with their own values and be happy.

If your functions are taking arguments, transforming them into a set of results without interaction of variables that are outside of the function, then you'll want to keep them as they are: just plain functions.

So, to sum all that up, it's a matter of software design, and there are plenty of books on the topics, on Internet and in libraries. I'm pretty sure you can find a SO question about "[what's the](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143390/recommended-reading-for-object-oriented-application-design-architecture) [best OO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524227/best-resources-to-learn-oo-design-and-analysis) [software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349627/good-reference-for-object-oriented-design) [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755028/a-good-resource-or-book-for-architecting-object-oriented-software) [book?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400538/best-books-for-object-oriented-software-designing-for-large-scale-systems)"

3. Is it better to 'install' my module or use it like a external file?

it's always better to install modules, using `distutils`/`setuptools` when you are distributing your code. And to help you develop your software, you'd better use a tool like `zc.buildout` or `virtualenv` (the first one being more powerful, but more sophisticated and usually is useful when you need a dev env build system, and the second one is really simple to use and does help get your environment ready for the development).

You can find tutorials for both there:

- http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/
- http://www.buildout.org/docs/tutorial.html

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to create a class in python, but the use of classes would help you wrap up functions and variables into an object.